# Alert manager/prometheus alert to Microsoft teams

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am setting up the monitoring for the Linux server and send alerts to Microsoft teams. I have set up the Prometheus monitoring. Now how do I send alerts to teams? I have installed everything on the centos 7 machines. Can anyone please guide me in this.

Comment: Have you installed [prom2teams](https://github.com/idealista/prom2teams) or any other adapter ?

Comment: I saw the prom2teams option, but this method is for Kubernetes.  I am not running this as containers. How do we add prom2teams on centos7 ? Is there any other options

Comment: You would have to make the install (nginx+uwsgi+prom2teams). Ask if you have troubles.

Comment: Thank you. I successfully installed prom2teams on my linux server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [prom2teams](https://github.com/idealista/prom2teams) which is a Python webserver that receives alerts from Prometheus Alertmanager and forwards it to Microsoft Teams.

You can install it with pip3:

```
pip3 install prom2teams
```